# WordPress Jnews theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I got an issue with the page loop feature
[an image of how it looks in edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C83p3.png)
even with me checking this enabled
[pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DePSb.png)
the pagination is not showing it used to be like this
[an example of how it used to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuCR6.jpg)
now it is not there it is gone

I tried adding functions and editing the php files for the theme (Landing Builder, index, landing page template)

but nothing shows except once by mistake when i was editing the php file and trying to draw them myself 2 arrows were displayed but that's all

[Site Link](http://thf.markanthonyonline.com/)

If not possible:

[pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFrhY.png)

I want to change this from next to prev and make it numbers like this

[what I want it to be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oVWI.jpg)

and I want it centered like it

I tried changing some things in here
[settings of module 22 in jnews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GsEx.png)